# Practical application of "Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes, and Barbed Wire"?

Tags: language-agnostic, functional-programming, theory

First of all, the goofy title is directly referencing this paper:

http://eprints.eemcs.utwente.nl/7281/01/db-utwente-40501F46.pdf

I understand the theoretical value of this, as it models most, if not all, programming semantics.

What problems are most efficiently and practically solved with a programming paradigm based on this? What problems are not?

Imagine entire programs written where 80% of all the logic involved these operators. I wonder if a language that forced the operators on the user could take advantage of their structure...

Comment: Don't know _what_ I'm meant to do with a PostScript file. Don't have a PostScript printer sitting here handy.

Comment: can you supply a pdf or html version of this paper as it is not easy to read postscript on many computers.

Comment: Your PDF reader can't read postscript?  Time to upgrade to a computer from some time after 1950, methinks.

Comment: @John, it's a pretty unique title, you can find the pdf if you cared.

Comment: Apologies. I've updated with a pdf link.

Comment: I didn't care. I thought @Jeremy might care, in which case he should post a PDF, and not a PostScript file that few can read.

Comment: @John Yeah, didn't even notice I was posting a ps file since it just opened fine for me. Again, sorry.

Comment: @Jeremy: Apology accepted. Which reader do you use that works with .ps files?

Comment: @John 'evince'. comes standard with ubuntu. although, I thought most adobe readers can read ps files, too.

Comment: I downloaded gsview and ghostscript for windows here http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/

Comment: @Jeremy: sort of what I thought. The question is a bit academic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This paper is one in a long series of related theoretical explorations.  The research area is what the functional programmers call *generic programming* (which confusingly is different from what C++ programmers call generic programming).  The idea is that you write your functions in such a way that **when you define a new data type, you automatically get new code to go with it**.  A classic problem people would like to solve this way is to write an image of the data to disk and later read back isomorphic data from the disk image.

If you want to get a feel for practical applications of these ideas, I recommend Ralf Hinze's excellent paper [Generics for the Masses](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/Masses.pdf), which shows how you can try out all these wacky ideas in plain old [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/).  For example, I have used these techniques to implement capture-avoiding substitution for very complicated intermediate languages inside compilers.

Ralf has written a number of good papers on generic programming, as has Jeremy Gibbons.  Their stuff is not quite as far out as bananas, lenses, and so on...

Comment: Great! Thanks for the paper link. Though, generics wasn't what I got out the 'Bananas'. Maybe I'll have to re-re-re-re-...-re-read it and look for that. (Though, maybe that's buried in the Category theory part that I don't grasp well.)

Comment: It seems that the link you have to Generics for the Masses is dead. Here is another: http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/Masses.pdf

Answer (score 2):

What this means is that solutions which can be modelled in one paradigm can also be modelled in the other, and that one can be programmatically converted into the other.

Now, certain problems are more easily solved in one paradigm than in the other. Also, it's easier to prove properties in one paradigm than in the other. So if you can show such equivalence, you open the door to solving certain problems in the easier, and then converting the solution into the desired paradigm.

This is similar to the monads thingy. The big deal with monads is not how do you write one. The big deal with them is that there is tons of theorems about monads which can be applied once you reduce your problem to a monad. The same principle applies here.

Comment: Right. This applies to all paradigms. (I mean, if I was asking about object oriented programming, this would hold true). But what can I *get* out of it?

Comment: As a programmer or as a researcher? As a programmer, nothing, really. As a researcher... well, I'm not qualified to answer that. :-)